# twitter bootstrap override and custom styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, overriding, customization, less

I am in need of help regarding:

1. Twitter Bootstrap
2. LESS
3. Simpless (optional)

I am using twitter bootstrap and I modified the variables.less to meet my color scheme and also I use custom.less for my layout etc. I use simpless by wearkiss to compile (or whatever it is called) less to css.

I use include my custom.less into "bootstrap.less" in the end @import "custom.less" and it generates single *.css file for me which uptil now I have been satisfied with, but now I need to separate core bootstrap.css and my custom.css, now here is the issue I am facing, I am using core classes in my custom.less file like:

1. .btn
2. .btn-primary and also mixins etc. etc.

And without including the core into my custom.less I cannot include (.btn) etc etc. What options do I have in order to utilize core classes (I don't want to rewrite what is already present in core) and still be able to separate core *.css and my custom.css?

Answer (score 3):

### Available with LESS 1.5

As of LESS 1.5, you can do an import of a file for reference purposes only, which allows you access the classes and mixins without the file generating its own output css. You would do so like so in your `custom.less` file:

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap.less";
```

Comment: Thanks ScottS, I will give it a try and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The thing we do here is make 2 files, `custom.less` and `style.less`. These look a bit like this:

**style.less**

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
@import "custom.less"; /* Overrides the bootstrap.less */
... Other imports
```

**custom.less**

```
/* Some custom styles here, that override the bootstrap.less */
...
```

You have to compile the style.less.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am already doing similar logic. I want two separate stylesheets. So I can easily customize the one file or other without compiling both together into one file. I am planning to use child themes and I want to allow the user to change the main "bootstrap.css" to their needs color etc and also want to allow them to utlize my parent theme "custom.css" if they like it (as it will contain the site layouts etc etc) or add their own combination.

Comment: So you want to keep the 2 seperate?

Comment: Yes I do want to keep two separate stylesheets.

Comment: Well, you could just compile your bootstrap file, and compile your custom file after that. Then you include them into your website, placing the custom include after the bootstrap include.

Comment: :), its not what I want, I want to utilize the "less" inheritance type feature, I want to utilize the twitter bootstrap core classes , .btn, .btn-large, .btn-primary, .table, etc etc into my custom.less file like '.my-button {.btn; .btn-primary}' etc.

Comment: Ah, then you should have another style.less for every theme you want to make.